# Return cached array instead of Realtime Database array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have 3 separate js files, one js file has function that i export and access on the other two js file. The purpose of the function is to get data from realtime database firebase once, when the function is called for the first time it will get data from database and store it on array outside the function. Then on second call, it will just return the array that contains data from database.

```js
let mySub = [];
export function getMySub(id) { // get users subjects
  if (mySub.length !== 0) {
    console.log('From Array SUBJECTS');
    return mySub;
  } else if (mySub.length == 0) {
    get(child(path, "General")).then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var data = childSnapshot.val();
        if (data.INS_SYS_ID == id) {
          mySub.push([data.COURSE_NAME, data.SECTION, childSnapshot.key, data.ENROLLED_STUDENTS]);
        }
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
    console.log('From DB SUBJECTS');
    return mySub;
  }
}
```

It works like this, if the mySub array length is not equal to zero the function will just return the array. if the array length is equal to zero it will get data from database and store it to mySub.

I also have a function on that same js file that updates the mySub array when i need to.

```js
export function updateDisplayedSub(coursename, section, key, enrolledStudents) {
  mySub.push([coursename, section, key, enrolledStudents]);
}
```

Now here is my problem, whenever i call the function that updates mySub array and call the function getMySub(id). it returns array that reads from database instead of returning the existing array that i updated.

updateDisplayedSub and getMySub is called on different js file, does this affect? I'm using this function to avoid too many reads and conserve bandwidth on my free tier hosting firebase.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to invent [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Your current method falls short because if you vary the `id` parameter, there's no way of telling if the cached data in `mySub` refers to that `id` or not. This will likely cause bugs.

Instead, we can write a [higher order function](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-intro-to-higher-order-functions-in-javascript-1a014f89c6b/) that returns a function that wraps your existing function:

```
const memoizeUnary = (f) => {
    const map = new Map();
    return (v, skipCached) => {
        if (!skipCached && map.has(v)) {
            return map.get(v);
        }
        else {
            const r = f(v);
            map.set(v, r);
            return r;
        }
    };
};
```

and use it to wrap another function:

```
function foo(v) {
    console.log("foo invoked");
    return `hello ${v}`;
}

const memoizedFoo = memoizeUnary(foo);
```

Now, if we call

```
memoizedFoo("monkey")
```

for the first time, the function that it wraps will be invoked, its return value stored in a map and then returned to the caller.

The second time we call

```
memoizedFoo("monkey")
```

the function it wraps will not be called, and the cached return value for parameter `"monkey"` will be retrieved and returned to the caller.

If you want to reset the cache and fetch from the wrapped function again, you can add an optional parameter, `true` to skip the cache, re-fetch and store the new value in the cache:

```
memoizedFoo("monkey", true)
```

Pop open the snippet below to see this in action:

```js
const memoizeUnary = (f) => {
  const map = new Map();
  return (v, skipCached) => {
    if (!skipCached && map.has(v)) {
      return map.get(v);
    } else {
      const r = f(v);
      map.set(v, r);
      return r;
    }
  };
};

function foo(v) {
  console.log("foo invoked");
  return `hello ${v}`;
}
const memoizedFoo = memoizeUnary(foo);
memoizedFoo("a");
memoizedFoo("a");
memoizedFoo("a");
memoizedFoo("a");
memoizedFoo("a");
memoizedFoo("a", true);
memoizedFoo("a");
memoizedFoo("a");
memoizedFoo("a");
```

Notice how, even though we call `memoizedFoo("a")` multiple times, the function it wraps is only called for the first time or if we supply a second `true` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i might apply that method on future development. I found the error, fetching of data to my array is so fast that it does not have any value yet; so it will really fetch data from DB instead of returning the array. What i did is i put an interval that checks the array length if it's zero; if not then ill call the function. Anyway thanks again for answering.